# The eigenvalues of a matrix with homogenous entries is also homogenous

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, homogeneous-equation

Consider a matrix depending on a parameter $\xi$:
$$
A(\xi)=\begin{pmatrix} a_{11}(\xi) & a_{12}(\xi) & \cdots & a_{1n}(\xi) \\ a_{21}(\xi) & a_{22}(\xi) & \cdots & a_{2n}(\xi) \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\  a_{n1}(\xi) & a_{n2}(\xi) & \cdots & a_{nn}(\xi)\end{pmatrix},
$$
where $\xi \in \mathbb{R}.$ We assume all the entries $a_{ij}(\xi)$ is homogenous with degree $1,$ that is
$$
a_{ij}(k \xi)=k a_{ij}(\xi), \qquad \forall k>0.
$$
I am not sure whether or not the eigenvalues of $A(\xi)$ are also homogenous with degree $1$?

**Inspired by @NicNic8 's answer, now we make an additional assumption(maybe could be removed) that "all the eigenvalues of $A(\xi)$ are distinct for any $\xi \in \mathbb{R}$."**

The characteristic polynomial of $A(\xi)$ is
\begin{equation}
\lambda^n(\xi)+c_1(\xi)\lambda^{n-1}(\xi)+\cdots+c_n(\xi)=0,
\end{equation}
and clearly $c_i(\xi)$ is a homogenous function with degree $i.$ Then for any positive constant $k,$ we have
$$
\lambda^n(k\xi)+kc_1(\xi)\lambda^{n-1}(k\xi)+\cdots+k^nc_n(\xi)=0,
$$
or equivalently
$$
(\lambda(k\xi)/k)^n+c_1(\xi)(\lambda(k\xi)/k)^{n-1}+\cdots+c_n(\xi)=0.
$$
We denote the eigenvalues of $A(\xi)$ by $\{\lambda_1(\xi),\cdots,\lambda_n(\xi)\}$ and denote the eigenvalues of $A(k\xi)$ by $\{\lambda_1(k\xi),\cdots,\lambda_n(k\xi)\},$ then we have the following two sets are equal for any $\xi \in \mathbb{R}$:

\begin{equation}
\{\lambda_1(\xi),\cdots,\lambda_n(\xi)\}=\{\lambda_1(k\xi)/k,\cdots,\lambda_n(k\xi)/k\}, \quad \forall k>0.
\end{equation}
since the roots of the reciprocally third equation and the last equation are the same. **That is the conclusion of @lonzaleggiera .**

However, we still need to show that
$$
\lambda_i(\xi)=\lambda_i(k\xi)/k, \quad \text{for} \  i=1,\cdots,n, \forall \xi \in \mathbb{R}, \forall k>0.
$$
For example, how to exclude the following situation
$$
\lambda_1(\xi_0)=\lambda_2(k\xi_0)/k_0, \quad \text{and} \quad \lambda_1(\xi_0)\neq\lambda_1(k\xi_0)/k_0
$$
at some $(\xi_0,k_0)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\ed{\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}}$
If $\ a_{ij}(\xi)\ $ are all homogeneous with degree $\ r\ $, then $\ A(\xi)=\xi^rA(1)\ $.
Let $\ \mu_1,\mu_2,\dots,\mu_m\ $ be the eigenvalues of $\ A(1)\ $ and $\ L_1,L_2,\dots,L_m\ $ the corresponding eigenspaces. Then for $\ v\in L_i\ $
\begin{align}
A(\xi)v&=\xi^r A(1)v\\
&=\xi^r\mu_iv\ .
\end{align}
Thus, for each $\ i\ $, $\ L_i\ $ is an eigenspace  of $\ A(\xi)\ $ corresponding to an eigenvalue $\ \xi^r\mu_i\ $. Conversely, if $\ \lambda_i(\xi)\ $ is an eigenvalue of $\ A(\xi)\ $ corresponding to an eigenvector $\ v\ ,$ then
\begin{align}
\lambda_i(\xi) v&=A(\xi)v\\
&=\xi^rA(1)v\ .
\end{align}
Therefore,  for $\ \xi\ne0\ $, $\ v\ $ must be an eigenvector of $\ A(1)\ $ corresponding to an eigenvalue $\ \frac{\lambda_i(\xi)}{\xi^r}\ $, and must belong to $\ L_j\ $ for some $\ j\ ,$ thus giving $\ \lambda_i(\xi)=\mu_j\xi^r\ $. Since $\ A(0)=0\ $ has just the single eigenvalue $\ 0\ $, it remains true that $\ \mu_j\xi^r\ $ is an eigenvalue of $\ A(\xi)\ $ for $\ \xi=0\ $. Thus, for all $\ \xi\ $, the eigenvalues of $\ A(\xi)\ $ are
$$
\mu_1\xi^r,\mu_ 2\xi^r,\dots,\mu_m\xi^r\ .
$$
Note that this only shows that *there exists* a set of homogeneous functions $\ \lambda_i(\xi)\ed\mu_{p(i)}\xi^r\ $, for some $\ p:\{1,2,\dots,n\}\rightarrow \{1,2,\dots,m\}\ $, such that $\ \lambda_1(\xi),\lambda_2(\xi),\dots,\lambda_n(\xi)\ $ are the eigenvalues of $\ A(\xi)\ $.  Since the indexing of the eigenvalues of $\ A(\xi)\ $ can be arbitrarily chosen, however, the functions $\ \lambda_1(\xi),\lambda_2(\xi),\dots,\lambda_n(\xi)\ $ are not uniquely defined, and it will always be possible to choose them to be non-homogeneous.

**Reply to OP's comment below**

It's unnecessary to *assume* anything about the multiplicities (whether geometric or algebraic) of the eigenvalues of $\ A(\xi)\ $, since it follows automatically from the fact that $\ A(\xi)=$$\,\xi^rA(1)\ $ that for $\ \xi\ne0\ $ they must be identical to  those of the eigenvalues of $\ A(1)\ $. If $\ m_i\ $ is the algebraic multiplicity of $\ \mu_i\ $, then the characteristic polynomial of $\ A(1)\ $ is
$$
\prod_{i=1}^m\big(x-\mu_i\big)^{m_i}\ ,
$$
and from the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, we get
$$
0_{n\times n}=\prod_{i=1}^m\big(A(1)-\mu_i\big)^{m_i}\ .
$$
Multiplying this equation by $\ \xi^{rn}\ $, and noting that $\ \sum_\limits{i=1}^mm_i=n\ $, we get
\begin{align}
0_{n\times n}&=\prod_{i=1}^m\big(\xi^rA(1)-\xi^r\lambda_i\big)^{m_i}\\
&=\prod_{i=1}^m\big(A(\xi)-\xi^r\lambda_i\big)^{m_i}\ .
\end{align}
Thus, the characteristic polynomial of $\ A(\xi)\ $ must be
$$
\prod_{i=1}^m\big(x-\xi^r\mu_i\big)^{m_i}\ ,
$$
and $\ m_i\ $ is the algebraic multiplicity of the eigenvalue $\ \xi^r\mu_i\ $.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But here $\lambda_i$ and $v$ all depend on $\xi.$ As in your answer, you proved that the two sets $\{\xi^r\lambda_1(1),\cdots,\xi^r\lambda_m(1) \}$ and $\{\lambda_1(\xi),\cdots,\lambda_m(\xi) \}$ are equal for all $\xi$. (Here we need to assume the algebraic multiplicities of every eigenvalues of $A(\xi)$ are constant for all $\xi \in \mathbb{R}$ otherwise the numbers of different eigenvalues could differ for $A(\xi)$ and $A(1)$ . ) But how to prove $\xi^r\lambda_1(1)=\lambda_1(\xi)$ for any $\xi$? I have edited my question to make it clearer.

Comment: No, I *explicitly defined*  $\ \lambda_i\ $ to be eigenvalues of the matrix $\ A(\color{red}{1})\ $, which is *fixed* and independent of $\ \xi\ $, and therefore so  are the $\ \lambda_i\ $ and their associated eigenspaces $\ L_i\ $.

Comment: I've just realised that my using the same symbols $\ \lambda_i\ $ for the fixed eigenvalues of $\ A(1)\ $ that you used for the non-fixed eigenvalues of $\ A(\xi)\ $ is likely to have led to some confusion. I've now updated my answer to use $\ \mu_i\ $ for the eigenvalues of $\ A(1)\ $. I also glossed over the fact that your functions $\ \lambda_i(\xi)\ $ are not uniquely defined. My answer only shows that you can *choose* them to be homogeneous, but there is no *necessity* for them to be so chosen.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I think we can assume that $A(\xi)$ is continuous with respect to $\xi$  and simply denote $\lambda_1(\xi_0)=\xi^r_0 \mu_1$ then for some $\xi_0.$ Then $\lambda_1(\xi)$ is always $\xi^r \mu_1$ for any $\xi$ since $\lambda_1(\xi)$ is continuous.  (Since the question is not an exercise from textbook , so I can provide  some properties of $A(\xi)$ if necessary.)

Answer (score 2):

From your definition, $A(k\zeta) =kA(\zeta)$.  Assuming A is diagonalizable (which must be the case for A to have eigenvalues), $A=U\Sigma U^T$, which implies $kA=U(k\Sigma)U^T$.

$U$ is a matrix of eigenvectors.  Let $u$ be a column of $U$, then $u$ is an eigenvector.  Therefore, $Au = \lambda u$, for some scalar $\lambda$.  Is $ku$ an eigenvector for some scalar $k$?  Yes: $A(ku) = kAu = k\lambda u$.  Therefore, any scaled eigenvector is also an eigenvector.

Comment: I am confused  how to show that the eigenvector matrix $U$ is also homogenous with degree 1?

Comment: @ventdelapaix Edited; does that answer your question?

Comment: I am afraid not. What you added seems a trivial fact. Maybe I didn't elaborate my question. As in your answer, the matrix $U$ is also depending on the parameter $\zeta$, then $kU(\zeta)\Sigma(\zeta)U^{-1}(\zeta)=kA(\zeta)=A(k\zeta)=U(k\zeta)\Sigma(k\zeta)U^{-1}(k\zeta).$ If we could show that $U(k\zeta)=kU(\zeta),$ then we can deduce that $k\Sigma(\zeta)=\Sigma(k\zeta).$ I have edited my question.